# My Python unittest script fails in Eclipse PyDev but works in Spyder

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

I am running Springsource Tool Suite  3.9.7.RELEASE with the PyDev 7.5.0 plugin.  Eclipse Pydev is giving me an error with unittest cases which I do not get in Spyder.

I have constructed the following test script:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest import TextTestRunner

class Test1(TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        print("Running Test1 - This should not appear")
        self.assertTrue(True, "Test1")

class Test2(TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        print("Running Test2 - This should not appear")
        self.assertTrue(True, "Test2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = TextTestRunner()
    print("Finished Running - This should appear")
```

When I run it from STS using Run As/Python unit-test it gives the following output:-

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

Running Test1 - This should not appear
Running Test2 - This should not appear
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

When I run exactly the same scipt in Spyder is gives me:-

```
Finished Running - This should appear
```

The Spyder output is what I would expect and want.  It looks like PyDev is grabbing every unittest TestCase object it can find and running them all when TextTestRunner is instantiated.

I have created this trivial example, but it arose from a real world project I am working on which uses both Python and Java.  I can only develop it using Eclipse PyDev.  I need to be able to specify which test cases I run using TextTestRunnner's run() method in the normal way. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Not having used Eclipse for a long time, I would guess that you should not use "Run as unittest", but just "Run" (or run as script, don't remember the wording)

Comment: Ah, so I just create a module which does nothing except import the tests I need, and run that as Run As/Python unit-test.  That works as I want.  Thank you for the reply, I would not have guessed that on my own.